# Get time until next occurrence of 6pm?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a thread that is only set to run within a certain period otherwise it's put on delay. From the time of running that threads of a certain Boolean value if true, then it should be delayed by X amount of time from current time to 18:00. Is there a quick way doing this in c#?

Comment: Do you mean that the thread starts, and if it's 15:10, then the thread should sleep for two hours and fifty minutes? Sounds like [you want `DateTime.Subtract()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes,  but if it's 21:00 it should also get me the number of minutes to 18:00 the next day. Date time objects don't handle that kind of stuff, from what I know. I could be wrong though

Comment: Correct, they don't. You'd use an `if`statement to write that part.

Comment: By the way, if you're a native speaker of English, your question shows an astonishing lack of effort to communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now; 
        
        DateTime tomorrow = today.Add(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0));
        
        DateTime tomorrowAtSix = new DateTime(tomorrow.Year, tomorrow.Month, tomorrow.Day, 18,0,0 ); 
        
        TimeSpan diff = tomorrowAtSix.Subtract(DateTime.Now); 
        
        double hoursFromNow = 0d; 
        double minutesFromNow = 0d; 
        if(diff.TotalHours > 24d) // next 6pm is tomorrow
        {
             hoursFromNow = diff.TotalHours - 24d; 
             minutesFromNow = diff.TotalMinutes - (24d * 60d); 
        }
        else  // next 6pm is today
        {
             hoursFromNow = diff.TotalHours;
             minutesFromNow = diff.TotalMinutes; 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract DateTime objects which will return a TimeSpan

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. How can I get the time in minutes from current time to the next 18:00 regardless of the day (whether today or tomorrow).